# Reference type variable from enclosing scope in type annotation

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have two nested classes and the outer one is generic.

The inner one has a reference to the outer one.

How can I annotate the reference that the inner one has to the outer one, so that the `reveal_type` at the bottom of the code snippet below works properly?

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

_T = TypeVar("_T")

class Outer(Generic[_T]):
    class Inner:
        outer_ref: Outer  # <- What goes here?

        def __init__(self, outer_ref: Outer[_T]) -> None:
            self.outer_ref = outer_ref

    def produce_inner(self) -> Inner:
        return Outer.Inner(self)


o: Outer[int] = Outer()
reveal_type(o.produce_inner().outer_ref)  # Should be `Outer[int]`.
```

I tried typing `outer_ref` as `outer_ref: Outer` but that will reveal `Outer[unknown]`.

If I type `outer_ref` as `outer_ref: Outer[_T]` I get a warning saying that the variable has no meaning there, Mypy will suggest I add `Generic[_T]` or `Protocol[_T]` to `Inner`, and the revealed type is `Outer[_T@Outer]`.

Notice that MyPy does not seem to have any issues with the type annotation `outer_ref: Outer[_T]` in the signature of `Inner.__init__`.

Answer (score 4):

You need `Inner` to also be a `Generic`, with its own type parameter, and to tie the two parameters together through an annotation on `produce_inner`:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

_T = TypeVar("_T")
_I = TypeVar("_I")

class Outer(Generic[_T]):
    class Inner(Generic[_I]):
        def __init__(self, outer_ref: Outer[_I]) -> None:
            self.outer_ref = outer_ref

    def produce_inner(self) -> Inner[_T]:
        return Outer.Inner(self)


o: Outer[int] = Outer()
reveal_type(o.produce_inner().outer_ref)  # `Outer[int]`
```

Comment: I get that this works. But is this the _only_ way to go about it? Ignorance is cheeky, but I don't get why I **need** to do it this way.

Comment: The reference inside an instance of `Inner` needs to record, in some way, the type parameter of the `Outer` that it points to.  You might be able to imagine some more elegant syntax for this for the specific case of a nested class, but I don't think one actually exists in Python's type system.  Nested classes *in general* are pretty awkward IMO, and I almost never use them, even in cases where they might intuitively make sense.

Comment: The part left unexplained here is the idea of ['forward references'](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references), which allows you to refer to the type before it is completely defined. This explains in part why you need to do it this way - you cannot refer to a type that has yet to be defined (or is in the process of being defined), at least not without a forward reference. The other half of the why is what @samwise explains in the previous comment.

Comment: Note that in current versions of Python quoting the forward reference isn't necessary (I do it kind of reflexively because it's more backward compatible; mypy works either way).  I'll remove that from this answer though since it seems like it's distracting from the actual fix.

Comment: @Samwise what version? Still looks necessary to me on Python 3.11 unless you do `from __future__ import annotations`